# Swift 4 regex custom validation

Tags: swift, regex, validation

i need some help to write correct regex validation. I want password with no spaces, min. 6 symbols, doesn't matter numbers or letters or symbols. Alphabet a-zA-Z and а-яА-Я(RU). How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{6,}$"
```

You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284607/how-to-implement-a-regex-for-password-validation-in-swift)