# Use RegEx to validate a password on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I need to validate a user's password against the following requirements:

- 8 or more characters.
- Contains 1 character and 1 number
- Can enter letters, numbers, and symbols

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this using a RegEx?

I've made attempts to solve this problem on my own, but nothing I've tried so far as worked. The code for my latest attempt is below.

```swift
func isPasswordHasEightCharacter(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passWordRegEx = "^.{8,}$"
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passWordRegEx)
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}

func isPasswordHasNumberAndCharacter(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passRegEx = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])"
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passRegEx)
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}

func isPasswordHasNumberAndCharacterSign(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passWordRegEx = "^(?!.[^a-zA-Z0-9@#${'$'}^+=])"
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passWordRegEx)
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your functions? What exactly happened? Any error was thrown?

Comment: By *letters, numbers and symbols*, do you mean *any non-whitespace chars*?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284607/how-to-implement-a-regex-for-password-validation-in-swift

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Comment: Ok, see the answer below.

Comment: @TiagoSilva when I check password: Pa$$w0rd each functions only first function return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` requires the full string to match and *consume* the whole input. Lookarounds - you are using lookaheads - do not consume text, that is, the texts they match are not added to the match value and the regex index stays where it was before attempting to match a lookaround pattern.

The last two parts can be thus fixed this way:

```
func isPasswordHasNumberAndCharacter(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passRegEx = "(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[^0-9]*[0-9].*"
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passRegEx)
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}

func isPasswordHasNumberAndCharacterSign(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passWordRegEx = "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+"
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passWordRegEx)
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

The first part is OK, though you do not need the `^` and `$` anchors (as the whole string input must match the pattern). However, to check a string  length you do not even need a regex: see [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string).

Note:

- `^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[^0-9]*[0-9].*\z` matches a string that contains at least one lowercase ASCII letter and at least one ASCII digit
- `^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+$` will match a string that only contains ASCII letters, digits and some specific symbols. If you inlude a `-` make sure it is at the end. Escape both `[` and `]` if you need to add them, too.

If you want to combine all that into 1 regex you could use

```
let passRegEx = "(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,}"
```

Or, if you are not using the regex with the `NSPredicate` `MATCHES`, with anchors:

```
let passRegEx = "\\A(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,}\\z"
```

Comment: The last function I want only containt  letters, numbers, and symbols like (!@#$%^&*). when I enter Special characters like " | ; , or katakana Japanese then return false

Comment: @HiệpChelsea So, do you mean to only match ASCII letters, numbers and some specific symbols then? I updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: yes, when I enter some characters I want show the message : "An invalid value has been entered "

Comment: @HiệpChelsea So, show it. The functions above should work now. Now you know why your regexps failed. The rest is up to you and does not pertain to the current question.

Comment: now I want white space in between text, top and last non-white space. 
I try : ^(?=\\S*)(?=\\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+(?=\\S*)$ but not work. can you help me?

Comment: @HiệpChelsea `(?=\\S*)` and `(?=\\s*)` are meaningless as you require an empty string to be present - it is always there. Can you please provide some example strings you want to pass and fail? Update https://regex101.com/r/g2OI5K/1 please with those examples.

Comment: @HiệpChelsea Try `"\\A(?=.{8})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+(?:\\s[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+)*\\z"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2OI5K/4)

Answer (score 1):

In this solution each requirement is checked individually to avoid complex regular expressions. This solution supports variants of characters like ôöệż etc

```
func validatePassword(_ password: String) -> Bool {
    //At least 8 characters
    if password.count < 8 {
        return false
    }

    //At least one digit
    if password.range(of: #"\d+"#, options: .regularExpression) == nil {
        return false
    }

    //At least one letter
    if password.range(of: #"\p{Alphabetic}+"#, options: .regularExpression) == nil {
        return false
    }

    //No whitespace charcters
    if password.range(of: #"\s+"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Some test cases

```
print(validatePassword("abc"))        // --> false
print(validatePassword("abcdefgh"))   // --> false
print(validatePassword("abcde fgh1")) // --> false
print(validatePassword("abcdefgh1"))  // --> true
print(validatePassword("abcåäö123"))  // --> true
print(validatePassword("ABC123€%&"))  // --> true
print(validatePassword("@èệżôøö123")) // --> true
```